# Rails 3.2 fields_for adding instead of updating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app where fields_for is adding new records instead of updating existing ones.

This is in the model for `costproject`:

```
has_many :costestimates, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :costestimates
```

This is part of the form:

```
   <%= simple_form_for @costproject do |f| %>
    ...
          <%= f.fields_for :costestimates do |builder| %>
              <fieldset>
                <% if builder.object.costproject.maintenance? %>
                    <% if builder.object.costcat.position.in?([3, 4, 9, 17, 18]) %>
                        <tr>
                          <td><%= builder.costcat.position %></td>
                          <td class="strongnowrap"><%= builder.costcat.category_name %></td>
                          <td><%= builder.input :amount, label: false, :input_html => {:style => 'width:100px'} %></td>
                          <% if builder.costcat.categorydesc != nil %>
                              <td>
                                <a rel="popover" data-content="<%= builder.costcat.categorydesc %>"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                              </td>
                          <% else %>
                              <td></td>
                          <% end %>
                          <td><%= builder.input :notes, label: false, :input_html => {:style => 'width:150px', :rows => 1} %></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <tr>
                      <td><%= builder.object.costcat.position %></td>
                      <td class="strongnowrap"><%= builder.object.costcat.category_name %></td>
                      <td><%= builder.input :amount, label: false, :input_html => {:style => 'width:100px'} %></td>
                      <% if builder.object.costcat.categorydesc != nil %>
                          <td>
                            <a rel="popover" data-content="<%= builder.object.costcat.categorydesc %>"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                          </td>
                      <% else %>
                          <td></td>
                      <% end %>
                      <td><%= builder.input :notes, label: false, :input_html => {:style => 'width:150px', :rows => 1} %></td>
                      <td><%= builder.object.id %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
              </fieldset>
          <% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, what is your trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the resource(s) to be edited to the `fields_for` method (as second argument for `fields_for`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :costestimates, @costproject.costestimates do |builder| %>
```

The documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for
(Search for the 'Or a collection to be used' example)

If you don't specify the resource(s) to be edited, then the `fields_for` will not include a `hidden_field` containing the resource(s) id(s) and therefore create a new record instead of updating the resource(s).

Comment: I also realize it wouldn't work for me if the data is in a dataTable (jquery).